# Symfony db interaction; PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, orm

So, i started using symfony, yesterday, and while following the tutorials, i ran into the database one.

After following the steps (creating the Entities and using the console commands to create the tables), it's now time to persist the entities inside the tables.

```
// Entity setup
$rep = new Entity\Reparto();
$rep->setDescrizione("Standard rep");
$rep->setTipo("0");
$rep->setIdAzienda(0);

// DB operation
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($rep); <-- Error here
$em->flush();

return new Response("Saved!");
```

This is the controller i call;
At the line `$em->persist($rep)` i receive, twice, the following exception:

```
"PDOException: could not find driver"
```

By removing that line, no exceptions are thrown, but obviously nothing happens

I already checked the php.ini file (there's only one):
I uncommented `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

`php -m` displays both PDO and pdo_mysql

I'm running the last version of Symfony (3.1) installed with composer, both on php 5.5.38, 5.6.18 and 7.0.3, running on windows 10 64-bit.
The whole thing is running on the dedicated webserver downloaded when you create a simfony project.

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm and nginx?

Comment: Yes, when i resorted to trying it on UWamp i did it multiple times, both restarting UWamp, the PHP engine, and the computer itself (i'm running it on a pc), to no avail

Comment: If you run `phpinfo()`, does it show that the `pdo_mysql` extension is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple versions of php installed on your environment.

First, take a look at PHP version used by Symfony and if the PDO mysql driver is enabled on it.

To do this, the easiest way is to look at the symfony debug bar, 
where the version is specified (3.1.X).

You will see the version of PHP and an access to phpinfo.  search on it if you have a line :  PDO drivers : mysql

also check your config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
```

Comment: thanks, but it somehow solved itself this morning, when i restarted the pc.
I only had a single php version enabled at a time, though, and all of them showed both PDO and pdo_mysql.

I have no idea what happened, but thanks anyway